proxy over vpn in flutter
I want to route all network traffic from android device to internal vpn service and to my desired ip and port.
I want to implement logic as same as "oxy proxy manager app" where user enters ip and port information and when pressed connect vpn profile is created in device setting -> Connection -> More connection settings -> VPN and user gets connected to proxy (Please use Oxy Proxy Manager App for more details). I want to implement same feature.
Below is my code
package com.bytesoftlab.true_vpn

import android.content.Intent
import android.net.VpnService
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor
import android.util.Log
import java.io.*
import java.net.InetSocketAddress
import java.net.Proxy
import java.net.Socket

class MyVpnService : VpnService() {

    private var vpnInterface: ParcelFileDescriptor? = null
    private val TAG = "MyVpnService"

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Log.d(TAG, "VPN Service Created")
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        vpnInterface?.close()
        vpnInterface = null
        Log.d(TAG, "VPN Service Destroyed")
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        val proxyIp = "81.95.232.128"
        val proxyPort = 3128

        Log.d(TAG, "Starting VPN with proxy IP: $proxyIp and port: $proxyPort")
        startVpn(proxyIp, proxyPort)

        return START_STICKY
    }

    private fun startVpn(proxyIp: String, proxyPort: Int) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Setting up VPN interface")

        if (vpnInterface != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "VPN interface already exists")
            return
        }

        val builder = Builder().apply {
            addAddress("10.0.0.2", 24)
            addRoute("0.0.0.0", 0)
            addDnsServer("8.8.8.8")
            addDnsServer("8.8.4.4")
            setSession("InternalVPN")
            setMtu(1500)
        }

        vpnInterface = builder.establish()

        if (vpnInterface == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to establish VPN interface")
            return
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "VPN Interface Established successfully")
        routeTrafficThroughHttpProxy(proxyIp, proxyPort)
    }

    private fun routeTrafficThroughHttpProxy(proxyIp: String, proxyPort: Int) {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "Connecting to HTTP proxy $proxyIp:$proxyPort")
            val proxy = Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, InetSocketAddress(proxyIp, proxyPort))

            val socket = Socket(proxy)
            socket.connect(InetSocketAddress("8.8.8.8", 80), 10000) // Test connection
            Log.d(TAG, "Proxy connection established successfully")

            val vpnInput: InputStream = FileInputStream(vpnInterface!!.fileDescriptor)
            val vpnOutput: OutputStream = FileOutputStream(vpnInterface!!.fileDescriptor)
            val proxyOutput = socket.getOutputStream()
            val proxyInput = socket.getInputStream()

            vpnInput.use { vpnIn ->
                proxyOutput.use { proxyOut ->
                    val buffer = ByteArray(32767)
                    while (true) {
                        val bytesRead = vpnIn.read(buffer)
                        if (bytesRead == -1) break
                        proxyOut.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                    }
                }
            }

            proxyInput.use { proxyIn ->
                vpnOutput.use { vpnOut ->
                    val buffer = ByteArray(32767)
                    while (true) {
                        val bytesRead = proxyIn.read(buffer)
                        if (bytesRead == -1) break
                        vpnOut.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error routing traffic through proxy: ${e.message}", e)
        }
    }
}

And the error is:
D/MyVpnService(13485): VPN Service Created
D/MyVpnService(13485): Starting VPN with proxy IP: 81.95.232.128 and port: 3128
D/MyVpnService(13485): Setting up VPN interface
D/MyVpnService(13485): VPN Interface Established successfully
D/MyVpnService(13485): Connecting to HTTP proxy 81.95.232.128:3128
E/MyVpnService(13485): Error routing traffic through proxy: Invalid Proxy
E/MyVpnService(13485): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Proxy
E/MyVpnService(13485):  at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:160)*
E/MyVpnService(13485):  at **com.bytesoftlab.true_vpn.MyVpnService.routeTrafficThroughHttpProxy(MyVpnService.kt:72)
E/MyVpnService(13485):  at com.bytesoftlab.true_vpn.MyVpnService.startVpn(MyVpnService.kt:64)
E/MyVpnService(13485):  at com.bytesoftlab.true_vpn.MyVpnService.onStartCommand(MyVpnService.kt:34)
E/MyVpnService(13485):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:5268)
E/MyVpnService(13485):  at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleServiceArgs(Unknown Source:0)
E/MyVpnService(13485):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2531)
E/MyVpnService(13485):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/MyVpnService(13485):  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
E/MyVpnService(13485):  at an`your text`droid.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
E/MyVpnService(13485):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8918)
E/MyVpnService(13485):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MyVpnService(13485):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:608)
E/MyVpnService(13485):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103)

I want to create an internal vpn server on an Android device and route traffic through my proxy ip and port (which I bought and has ip authentication in it).
